# Typescript: 2dimensional array with key of number, and value of array

Tags: typescript, multidimensional-array

```
interface ChatRoom {
  [key: number]: array;
}
```

Is there a way to declare 2dimensional array like a snippet I've provided?
The key must be number and the value must be array. Is there any other way to declare that array?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`type ChatRoom = any[][];`

or

`type ChatRoom = Array<Array<any>>;`

Change `any` for your desired type.

Comment: Does "any" take an array? I thought it takes only single object.

Comment: It takes anything you want. But it's already 2-dimension. Do you want 2-dimension holding a 3rd array?

Comment: Thanks for feedback, I've already solved this problem. 
I realized that I needed object with 2 dimensional array within and with key: number.